# GridView column header on click event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, gridview, header

In WPF, how can you fire an event when a GridView (inside a ListView) column header is clicked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the `GridViewColumnHeader.Click` event in the `ListView`:

```
<ListView GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler">
```